# Execute Terraform via Ansible "terraform" module. Set of strings required

Tags: variables, ansible, terraform

So I have the following Ansible playbook to execute a Terraform script:

```
    - name: run Terraform
      terraform: 
        project_path: "{{ terraform_base_dir }}"
        force_init: yes
        variables:
          cp_key: "{{ cp_key }}"
          cp_secret_key: "{{ cp_secret_key }}"
          cluster_name: "{{ cluster_name }}"
          template: "{{ template }}"
          zone: "{{ zone }}"
          size: "{{ size }}"
          disk_size: "{{ disk_size }}"
          key_pair: "{{ key_pair }}"
          security_groups: "{{ security_groups }}"
```

and the following Ansible variables:

```
terraform_base_dir: "/root/deploy_k8s/terraform"
cp_key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
cp_secret_key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
cluster_name: "test123"
template: "Linux Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64-bit"
zone: "at-vie-1"
size: "Medium"
disk_size: "100"
key_pair: "kp_xyz"
user: "ubuntu"
security_groups:
  - "k8s-{{ cluster_name }}"
  - "Jumphosts"
  - "mobile_network"
  - "home"
```

Executing the playbook, I get the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "backend_config": null,
            "binary_path": null,
            "force_init": true,
            "lock": true,
            "lock_timeout": null,
            "plan_file": null,
            "project_path": "/root/deploy_k8s/terraform",
            "purge_workspace": false,
            "state": "present",
            "state_file": null,
            "targets": [],
            "variables": {
                "cluster_name": "test123",
                "disk_size": "100",
                "cp_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "cp_secret_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "key_pair": "kp_xyz",
                "security_groups": [
                    "k8s-test123",
                    "Jumphosts",
                    "mobile_network",
                    "home"
                ],
                "size": "Medium",
                "template": "Linux Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64-bit",
                "zone": "at-vie-1"
            },
            "variables_file": null,
            "workspace": "default"
        }
    },
    "msg": "Terraform plan could not be created\r\nSTDOUT: Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...\nThe refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be\npersisted to local or remote state storage.\n\n\n------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\r\n\r\nSTDERR: \nError: Incorrect attribute value type\n\n  on build.tf line 28, in resource \"cp_compute\" \"master\":\n  28:   security_groups = \"${var.security_groups}\"\n\nInappropriate value for attribute \"security_groups\": set of string required.\n\n\nError: Incorrect attribute value type\n\n  on build.tf line 38, in resource \"cp_compute\" \"node01\":\n  38:   security_groups = \"${var.security_groups}\"\n\nInappropriate value for attribute \"security_groups\": set of string required.\n\n\nError: Incorrect attribute value type\n\n  on build.tf line 48, in resource \"cp_compute\" \"node02\":\n  48:   security_groups = \"${var.security_groups}\"\n\nInappropriate value for attribute \"security_groups\": set of string required.\n\n"
}
```

**Inappropriate value for attribute "security_groups": set of string required.**

The Terraform "build.tf" file is:

```
...
variable "security_groups" {}
...
resource "cp_compute" "master"  {
  display_name = "k8s-${var.cluster_name}-master"
  template = "${var.template}"
  zone = "${var.zone}"
  size = "${var.size}"
  disk_size = "${var.disk_size}"
  key_pair = "${var.key_pair}"
  security_groups = "${var.security_groups}"
}
...
```

Providing the security groups hard-coded in the .tf file works perfectly.

```
security_groups = ["k8s-test123","Jumphosts","mobile_network","home"]
```

Providing the exact same via an Ansible variable, it doesn't work.

Does someone have any hints what's wrong with the syntax of the variable?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you need to declare variable `"security_groups" {type="list"}` as a list for it to take multiple values

Defining this should ideally solve your issue.

Comment: Ok, that changed the behaviour, we're now one step further. I now get the following error message: `Error: Invalid character\n\n  on <value for var.security_groups> line 1:\n  (source code not available)\n\nSingle quotes are not valid. Use double quotes (\") to enclose 
strings.\n\n\n"`. Is it possible that the Ansible module is not correctly passing the item list?

Comment: seems to me related to the way terraform is interpreting the values passed from ansible. Can you try with simple name i.e `without space,- and _`. --> This will help us to identify the issue

Comment: I now added only one value: "default", but I get the exact same error message. It seems that the parsing/passing of an Ansible string list itself is the problem. Unfortunately I need to pass a string list for this specific use case.

Comment: that's fine just wanted to check that the error is not related to special characters. let me dig in more

Comment: @dom_weissb03 Did you manage to get this working? I am facing the same issue.